# converting buffer to string C++ boost

Tags: c++, string, boost, buffer

I have written client server  communication.  however during parsing my buffer on C++ client I lost most of my  data. I have  understood what the problem but still don't know how to solve it:
code:

```
            std::cout << b.max_size() <<std::endl;
    boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type bufs = b.prepare(50000);
    size_t n = socket.receive(bufs);
    // received data is "committed" from output sequence to input sequence
    b.commit(n);
    std::istream is(&b);
    std::string s;
    is >> s;
```

my buffer size = 5000 as I assigned ( the maximum size is 429496). My problem in this line with b.commit(n); std::istream is(&b); And the size of string s is 119, which is not acceptable .

Comment: Is there any other ways to convert buffer to string  because I used protocol buffer and I need to Parse it using object.ParseFromString(s);

Comment: `>>` is *formatted* I/O and stops at the first whitespace character.

Comment: Can I neglect this space  somehow

Comment: Not really familiar with boost.asio, but looking at the documentation, I'd try something like `boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type data = b.data(); std::string s(data.begin(), data.end());`.

Comment: Why not just use [`ParseFromIstream()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.ParseFromIstream.details) instead of doing the extra copy into a string?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the whole buffer, do like this:

```
streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = b.data();
std::string s(buffers_begin(bufs), buffers_begin(bufs) + b.size());
```

Or like this:

```
streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = b.data();
std::string s(buffers_begin(bufs), b.size());
```

Or:

```
string s(buffer_cast<const char*>(b.data()), b.size());
```

You can find the corresponding documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html).